# create countdown based on server hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I´m facing a need of creating a coundown to display when ever a certain promo will be over, all i have is front-end access via google tag manager, first i manage to get the server hour with js, now i need to set the countdown hour based on the server hour and not local hour.

```
 <script>
  // it´s giving the correct hour
  var getserver = new Date();
 getserver.setHours(getserver.getHours());
 var newtets = getserver.toUTCString();
 alert(newtets);



 // using a basic countdown
   var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
 var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();
/* 
 var now = new Date();
now.setHours(now.getHours());
var newnow = now.toUTCString();
i tried to replace now with newnow but is not working, how can i transform this
*/


// Find the distance between now an the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);

</script>
```

var now = new Date().getTime(); is what getting the time and use it to countdown, this is taking local time, how can i get var now = new Date().getTime(); to be server hour, which i obtained with the 1 script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get your updated server hour is using an ajax call. 
The problem is that the request to the server is not immediate so you will have a delay.

Maybe it would be better to get the user timezone and calculate the promo ending with this information.

You can get the user timezone offset using:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: i can edit the time an add the plus hour needed to  match the server, but the issue is that this is for different countries there for i cannot do that example, server its with spain hour, i will be shown also in central america this is why i need only the server hour

Comment: But the hour must be shown using the user local hour, isn't it? I think that the best solution is to add the user timezone offset to the server hour and not viceversa.

Comment: using new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); to replace new Date().getTime(); is giving wrong date, can you explain me how to use it exactly, im running a test with var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 28, 2017 23:59:59").getTimezoneOffset(); to ensure it matches but is not working

Comment: The `getTimezoneOffset();` method returns the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time (in minutes), so you must add the offset to your server created date.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f2318yb9/1/) you have a jsfiddle

Comment: i saw the file is almust want i need, but the date var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 28, 2017 23:59:59").getTime(); is count down meaning from now until that time it should display  0d 12h 7m 17s from central america and 0d 7h 7m 17s from spain, this basically is what im looking for

Comment: after using the last update you made, i will have to play with the  return new Date(time + offset * 60000); since is giving 6 hours plus, when i run this in spain i get 6 hours plus and in central america is on time